# Typescript Interface, reference one instance property for dynamic second property

Tags: javascript, typescript, interface, typescript-types

I want to use a property within a Typescript Interface's instance to compute a second property. I've been looking into Generics but I'm not successfully implementing this yet. :

Here's an example

```
// Here I define all valid names - works fine!

type ModalNames = 'payment' | 'source'

// This interface implements all expected payloads
//  for each name 

interface ModalPayloads {
  payment: {
    plan: string
  }
  source: {
    metadataId: string
  }
}


// How do I use the instance name
//  to grab the correct payload property?
export interface ShowModalPayload {
  name: ModalNames
  modalProps?: ModalPayloads[instance.name]
}
```

In other words, for a given `instance` of `ShowModalPayload`, I want to assign `modalProps` to a type derived from `instance.name`.
Hopefully this makes sense!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd use [generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html) for this:

```
export interface ShowModalPayload<K extends ModalNames> {
  name: K
  modalProps?: ModalPayloads[K]
}
```

Note the use of `ModalPayloads[K]` in place of `ModalPayloads[instance.name]`.  That's called a [lookup type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-1.html#keyof-and-lookup-types) and it allows you to describe the type of `m[k]` where `m` has type `ModalPayloads` and `k` has type `K`.

Anyway the `ShowModalPayload` interface is now generic in `K`, which should be one of the `ModalNames` literals:

```
declare const smpPayment: ShowModalPayload<'payment'>;
smpPayment.name // "payment"
smpPayment.modalProps // {plan: string} | undefined

declare const smpSource: ShowModalPayload<'source'>;
smpSource.name // "source"
smpSource.modalProps // {metadataId: string} | undefined
```

Those correspond to what you're looking for, I think.  Note that the following is still possible:

```
declare const smpWhoKnows: ShowModalPayload<ModalNames>
smpWhoKnows.name // ModalNames
smpWhoKnows.modalProps // {plan: string} | {metadataId: string} | undefined
```

which is possibly not what you want, but is not prohibited.  The above definition is probably sufficient for most use cases, though.

Hope that helps.  Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the quick response!
I am still getting an error -> 

`Type 'K' cannot be used to index type 'ModalPayloads'.`

Comment: I can't reproduce that error.  Have you provided a [mcve]?   If `ModalNames` has more values than `keyof ModalPayloads` you will get that error.

Comment: Aha - that must be it. Yes this is an incomplete example - let me dig in a little more. Thanks !